# Using "as" in an introductory clause

Tags: grammar

Is this considered an introductory clause? "as the lightning struck the tree, the people ran."

Comment: You can call it that, but It's not actually a clause; it's a **preposition phrase** headed by the prep "as", which contains an embedded subordinate content clause "the lightning struck the tree". Its function is that of **supplementary adjunct** of time. Like most supplements, it's not tightly integrated into clause structure, but loosely attached, set off from the rest of the clause by a comma, and in speech by a slight pause. Note though, that as a supplement it doesn't modify anything, but simply adds useful, though non-essential information about the situation.

Comment: "As" is not a preposition in this sentence. It is a conjunction connecting two clauses. In the sentence "This ​jacket ​costs ​twice as much as that one" "as" is a proposition--it establishes a relationship between two nouns.

Comment: No, it's a preposition. Refer to CGEL (Cambridge Grammar of The English Language) Ch 8 p697 and other references for evidence. It's just a matter of different complementation.

Comment: @Carrie: You probably haven't understood the correct use of this construction. A statement of the general form ***As** A happened, B happened* doesn't mean ***as = when = [immediately] after*** - it means ***as = while = at the same time as***. In short, unless the people ran *because / at the same time as* lightning was ***repeatedly*** striking the tree, it's not really a very "accurate" usage.

Comment: A preposition takes a noun phrase as its argument.  A conjunction takes a clause as its argument.  'As' (='while/when') is a conjunction.  {'When' = 'while/after' is a conjunction with ambiguous temporal connotations.)

Answer (score 1):

It is an "introductory clause" insofar as it begins the sentence, but it is also a dependent or subordinate clause: "as the lightning struck the tree" cannot stand on its own--to make sense it requires additional information, which is provided by "The people ran," an independent clause (it can stand on its own). "As" is referred to as a subordinate conjunction--it connects an independent clause and a subordinate clause.

"Introductory clause" simply refers to a dependent clause that begins a sentence--but these two clauses could easily be reversed without having any effect on meaning: "The people ran as the lightning struck the tree." No matter what order these two clauses appear in, on the other hand, one is always an independent clause, the other is always a subordinate clause.

Comment: Here's one source: https://owl.english.purdue.edu/engagement/2/1/37/         Here's another: http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/conjunctions.htm